# What are the differences between Ubuntu download servers

Tags: software-sources

1. Are all Ubuntu download servers an exact copy of the main server?
2. Can a software be on a server but not be on another server?
3. Can the version of a software be different on different servers?
4. Where is the main server?

Comment: Related: [Differences between servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260347/differences-between-servers), [What are mirrors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913180/what-are-mirrors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No. Servers need to get updated from the main server so some repositories will lag a little bit. Here is a [list of mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) with a column that states how far behind a server is. As you can see some are a week behind but you might also expect that this is due to localisation (translations in progress).
2. See 1. In general this is only the case when a server is updated and that mirror is not updated yet. I would assume this to be the case when a new release is out. The mirrors will need a bit of time to update.
3. See 1 and 2.
4. That would be [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com/) and/or [uk.archive.ubuntu.com](http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/) I would assume it to be in the United States and the 2nd to be in the United Kingdom. And I would consider both "main" servers.