# Cannot install wxmaxima in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, application-development

1. I am not able to install wxmaxima. The app is displayed in the software center and also starts installing but in dos not proceed to complete the installation.
2. What difference it makes when I change the source server (USA,main,Indian) option available in the Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install wxMaxima` from the command line?

Comment: 1. See the above comment and edit the output into your question. 2. That is just the download server where you download from the repositories, pick one close to you (or main if that is slow).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using the same version of Ubuntu (16.04). I did a simple search in the repository and came with this result:

```
$ apt search wxmaxima
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
wxmaxima/xenial 15.08.2-1 amd64
  GUI for the computer algebra system Maxima
```

This means you should be able to install this package with the  following command:

```
$ sudo apt install wxmaxima
```

In case you get any error, update your question with it.

For the second question, logically all the servers are supposed to be same as the main one. Yet, there can be a bit difference because of delay in updating and synchronizing between these servers and the main one. For more detailed answer you may check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/593244/214264).

Comment: Any success? any new update?

Comment: can u give me some suggestions I would like to be a small developer in ubuntu community , I only know C++

Comment: I liked ubuntu very much since 10 days of using it , its so simple and cute but has all that windows have in a much secured way. so I like to join this noble ubuntu community and contribute in its development

Comment: Have a look on https://community.ubuntu.com/